# Efficient Extracting items from list consisting from JSON objects

Tags: python, json, algorithm, parsing

I need to extract from certain url, which consists from json items - items that corresponds certain conditions. Like `item['status'] == 6`, and item['creationDate'] == 'today'. The goal is to make program faster retrieve data and deliver it to user. On url there are 10mb of data.
In my code, i first retrieve the whole list, and then sort it with certain conditions. After that i save job_ids of that result to 'checkpoint.txt' so program will be able to check if those objects were already parsed before, and do not repeat them in output. Here is my code for that:

```
def save_checkpoint(job_id):
    with open(checkpoint_file, 'a') as f:
        f.write(job_id + '\n')

def load_checkpoint():
    try:
        with open(checkpoint_file, 'r') as f:
            job_ids = set(f.read().strip().split('\n'))
    except FileNotFoundError:
        job_ids = set()
    return job_ids

def get_feed_items():
    json_data = get_json_from_url(feed_url)
    try:
        data = json.loads(json_data)
    except data == []:
        json_data == get_json_from_url(sub_url)
    items = []
    checkpoint = load_checkpoint()

    sorted_data = sorted(
        data,
        key=lambda sorted_data: datetime.strptime(data['job']['creationDate'], '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S'),
        reverse=True)


    for item in sorted_data[:20]:
        job_id = item['job']['id']
        if item['job']['status'] == 6 and job_id not in checkpoint:
            try:
                long_name = item['job']['name']
                name = long_name.split('_')[1]
                if item:
                    for history_item in item['tasks'][0]['history']:
                        item_data = {
                            'name': name,
                            'job_id': job_id,
                            'renderer': item['job']['renderer'],
                            'status': item['job']['status'],
                            'comment': history_item['comment'],
                        }
                    #print(f"Found new item: {item_data}")
                    items.append(item_data)
                save_checkpoint(job_id)
            except KeyError as a:
                raise a
        else:
            pass
    return items
```

What is the optimal solution for my task? what is the best way to sort data and retrieve needed items?
My bot will be working on local machine, and data server is updated every 5 sec.

The reason why im first retrieving everything - is because items are added randomly. and there is no chance to track new items nor by index, nor by anything else(as i suppose)).

Thats why i first retrieve all data, then sort by creationDate and status, then save approved data to checkpoint. And next time program will be running - it will check if there are any new items besides those that it parsed before, and add them if they exist. If not - `sleep`

How may i optimize my code? or maybe use deferent solution or algorithm for this case?

Comment: What are you hoping *except data == []:* will achieve (apart from a NameError exception). Also, why *except KeyError as a: raise a*? You might as well not have the try/except block at all

Comment: why not? can you explain? I think its a nice way to handle error. Also im receiving json data, which is placed into variable 'data' which looks like this: "{'job': {'id': '64779ec7b9361122b411aa72', 'jobId': 'c46dcc50-c714-4cc0-b6d9-bd459baaf413', 'clientLimit': 5, 'creationDate': '01.06.2023 00:23:51', 'finishDate': '01.01.0001 05:00:00', 'name': 'Farm_F202358116_c46dcc50-c714-4cc0-b6d9-bd459baaf413'...". keyerror is written because its an often error which is need to be handled. and i wrote it for myself mainly. To track the process

Comment: Im trying to understand which is fastest way to filter incoming data.

Comment: `sorteddata` isn't defined, there is nothing after the equals sign, and according to your code, you wanted to assign that `sorted` object to `sorteddata`. Also, you are using `data` as the argument of `lambda` but it is also the name you use in `sorted`.

Comment: You didn't share enough data, and it is really hard to guess what you are trying to do by looking at the code alone.

Comment: @ΞένηΓήινος data is a list of json items which are retrieved from 'feed_url' and in case if data server doesnt function and return empty lists - its using another working one. I wanted to sort items from `data` according to their creationDate. Also thanks for the notice. Thats pure accident)) Didn't notice and forget to delete.